# Error in ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] : replacement has length zero

Tags: r

Hello I am currently a first year and still learning R online classes, I am having an error message:
"Error in ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL" in R studio and I don't know why it's doing this, I took the data using read.csv and took the 2nd column and after that took the first two items of the 2nd column then compared the first item to the third item of the 2nd column here's my code:

```
dataGrade <- read.csv(file.choose(), fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

gradeColumn2 <- dataGrade[, 2]
twoGrades <- gradeColumn2[1:2]

ifelse(twoGrades[1] == gradeColumn2[3],
       cat("Grade", twoGrades[1],"is equal to Grade",gradeColumn2[3]),
       cat("Grade", twoGrades[1],"is not equal to Grade",gradeColumn2[3]))
```

The data in the csv file is

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Since you are checking condition of length 1 use `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse`.

```
dataGrade <- data.frame(GRADE.A = c(79, 89, 93),
                        GRADE.B = c(90, 92, 91))

gradeColumn2 <- dataGrade[, 2]
twoGrades <- gradeColumn2[1:2]

if(twoGrades[1] == gradeColumn2[3]) {
  cat("Grade", twoGrades[1],"is equal to Grade",gradeColumn2[3])
} else{
    cat("Grade", twoGrades[1],"is not equal to Grade",gradeColumn2[3])
}

#Grade 90 is not equal to Grade 91
```

Comment: Although the answer is correct, the reason is that ifelse() is the Conditional Element Selection, so it is designed to return a value. You need the structure if/else to execute actions.